# Laravel : How do I chain eager loading between four or more tables?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my current relationships

```
I -> belongsTo -> S //in model I
S -> belongsTo -> C //in model S
C -> belongsTo -> T //in model C

T -> hasMany -> C //in model T
C -> hasMany -> S //in model C
S -> hasMany -> I //in model S
```

Right now, I am able to eager load until `C` from `I` but how do I eager load until `T` also from `I`? I have tried several ways such as `I::with(['S.c'=>function($query){ $query->with('C.t') }])`

but they all spit out errors.

Comment: `I::with(['S', 'S.C', 'S.C.T'])`?

Comment: Notice: Laravel is extremely case sensitive!
You should call them like this:
`$model->S->C->T->property`

Comment: @Vohuman thanks! You might want to add that as an answer, though. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can eager load the descendant tables by using dot notation:

```
I::with(['S', 'S.C', 'S.C.T'])->get();
```